# Why Mailgun returns error 498 "No MX found for domain", when dig & online services find records?

Tags: dns, mailgun

We are trying to send messages via Mailgun API with PHP. Messages appear on app.mailgun.com logs just fine, but they are not delivered. Log gives the following status:

```
"delivery-status": {
        "attempt-no": 3,
        "description": "No MX for domain.tld'",
        "session-seconds": 0,
        "retry-seconds": 1800,
        "code": 498,
        "message": "No MX for domain.tld'"
},
```

Confirmed via `dig`, domain.tld uses Google's mailservers, ie.

```
domain.tld.     900 IN  MX  0 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
domain.tld.     900 IN  MX  5 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
domain.tld.     900 IN  MX  10 ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
domain.tld.     900 IN  MX  5 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
domain.tld.     900 IN  MX  10 ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
```

Same result for both nameservers for domain.tld. Also, same result when trying via e.g. mxtoolbox.com tool.

We tried sending to anotherdomain.tld, which also has known & working (non-Google) MX records, exactly the same 498 error.

Further, we tried sending to a gmail.com address, and yet:

```
 "delivery-status": {
        "attempt-no": 1,
        "description": "No MX for gmail.com'",
        "session-seconds": 0,
        "retry-seconds": 600,
        "code": 498,
        "message": "No MX for gmail.com'"
    },
```

The configured sending domain is a subdomain for domain.tld, it's verified and the account is upgraded. subdomain.domain.tld has Mailgun's MX records set.

I tried to search their documentation for references to `498` or `no mx for`, but all I found was examples without explanation: https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-events.html#examples

What does the error message mean? What can I do? I have full access to domain.tld's DNS and subdomain.domain.tld's Mailgun account.

Comment: can you send to other random domains (for example to gmail.com)? Can you send to @domain.tld addresses from gmail?

Comment: Sending to random domains is a good idea to try. @domain.tld addresses have been company's primary email accounts via G-Suite for over a year without problems, so MX for domain.tld is loud & clear.

Comment: @DusanBajic same thing happens when sending to random domains or to a gmail.com domain via Mailgun. Probably best to contact their support whether the error message is even correct…

Comment: I'm unsure should this be closed as off-topic because it is a result of a typographical (albeit programmatic) error and because the problem is not at all related to DNS nor Mailgun itself, which was the initial diagnosis. On the other hand, the question is voted up and is a good example to read the API's error messages even more carefully…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, this was an embarrassing typo. The error message is fine, but it should be inspected more carefully:

```
"delivery-status": {
        "attempt-no": 1,
        "description": "No MX for gmail.com'",
        "session-seconds": 0,
        "retry-seconds": 600,
        "code": 498,
        "message": "No MX for gmail.com'"
    },
```

The domain it looks for MX is `gmail.com'` not `gmail.com`, as the error message semi-clearly states.

The error was in the email producing code, which added extra single quotes to the address, nothing wrong with Mailgun or DNS.

Comment: Well, it is kind of a mailgun problem: If you enter forwarding emails like this:

'foo@bar.com','foo2@bar2.com'

it causes the problem you mentioned (which I also experienced).

You have to enter them like this for the forwarding to work as expected:

foo@bar.com,foo2@bar2.com

Mailgun should capture this and either fix it on input or raise an error.